# How to get the set of terms that occur in a search result?

Tags: java, lucene, solr, solrj, luke

Given the id/url of an indexed document in solr can I get the set of terms contained/indexed for that document?

This is done by Luke so I suspect http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler could help but I'm !sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the individual indexed terms for a field in a document you cannot use the LukeRequestHandler since it does not have that functionality. It can show you the index configuration and top terms per field but not the indexed terms for a document. For debugging purposes when you cannot use the Luke toolbox directly against your index I would advice you to use the Analysis tool in the admin interface where you can specify the field and the input text and it will show you all the steps performed by the analyzers for that specific field and the resulting tokens.